# What could be the possible causes for a clicking sound opposite to the direction of the turn from a front wheel drive vehicle?

Tags: noise, steering, maruti

I'm on the Indian sub-continent. The vehicle in question is a Maruti 800 MPFI ; motive power is provided by a Suzuki F8 engine driving the front wheels. The [steering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maruti_800#Steering), as per Wikipedia, is a Rack/Pinion type.

Upon turning the steering to the right - beyond a certain angle - something of a mechanical clicking sound emanates from the left front of the vehicle. The mudguard is clean enough, and there is nothing visible adhering to the tyre that could cause the sound.

Historically - I don't know whether this is relevant - there was one occasion when the **right** side was on jack with the front wheel off. A passer-by accidently released the valve on the jack, and the vehicle came down on the disc/hub on the front right side.

To get back to my present concern, I'm told by a mechanic that the axle to the front left must be replaced. It may be the cause that the axle is no longer true, and must be replaced. I'm curious whether the current noise may simply be a bad wheel bearing which could be replaced without replacing the entire axle assembly.

What could be the possible causes for a clicking sound opposite to the direction of the turn from a front wheel drive vehicle?

Comment: Sounds like cv axel. Generally the bad is the opposite to turn direction because the weight of car presses on it. so left turn sound, right is bad, and right turn noise left is bad, so would guess your left is bad. Be sure sound coming from low though, changed a buddies structs because his strut bearings were bad and making popping noise when turning. Hard turn and drive and see if it keeps clicking/popping or if it only makes  noises when actively turning

Comment: @Chris - You should write an answer, because from my reckoning, you're spot on.

Comment: @Chris: Bang on target. The noise only emanates beyond a certain angle when turning. What damage/s could it cause left untreated? p.s. Change your comment to answer, and let me flag it as the accepted one.

Comment: Generally if they go you lose power to the wheel. If happens turning or at speed could cause accident. Never left a bad one to see how long it lasts. I generally dont want to mess with suspension, stearing, breaks  and power in general, the mechanical stuff. The widgets and all that jazz, I dont mind putting off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like cv axel. Generally the bad side is the opposite to the turn direction because the weight of car presses on it. so a left turn sound, right side is bad, and right turn noise left side is bad, so would guess your left is bad. Be sure sound coming from low though, changed a buddies structs because his strut bearings were bad and making popping noise when turning. Hard turn and drive and see if it keeps clicking/popping or if it only makes  noises when actively turning